# Postgres - CRUD operations with arrays of composite types

Tags: arrays, postgresql, record, composite

One really neat feature of Postgres that I have only just discovered is the ability to define `composite type` - also referred to in their docs as `ROWS` and as `RECORDS`.  Consider the following example

```
CREATE TYPE dow_id AS
(
 tslot smallint,
 day smallint
);
```

Now consider the following tables

```
CREATE SEQUENCE test_id_seq INCREMENT 1 MINVALUE 1 MAXVALUE 2147483647 START 1 CACHE 1;

CREATE TABLE test_simple_array 
(
 id integer DEFAULT nextval('test_id_seq') NOT NULL,
 dx  integer []
);

CREATE TABLE test_composite_simple 
(
 id integer DEFAULT nextval('test_id_seq') NOT NULL,
 dx  dow_id
);

CREATE TABLE test_composite_array 
(
 id integer DEFAULT nextval('test_id_seq') NOT NULL,
 dx  dow_id[]
);
```

CRUD operations on the first two tables are relatively straightforward.  For example

```
INSERT INTO test_simple_array (dx) VALUES ('{1,1}');
INSERT INTO test_composite_simple (dx) VALUES (ROW(1,1));
```

However, I have not been able to figure out how to perform CRUD ops when the table has an `array of records/composite types` as in `test_composite_array`.  I have tried

```
INSERT INTO test_composite_array (dx) VALUES(ARRAY(ROW(1,1),ROW(1,2)));
```

which fails with the message

> ERROR: syntax error at or near "ROW"

and

```
INSERT INTO test_composite_array (dx) VALUES("{(1,1),(1,2)}");
```

which fails with the message

> ERROR: column "{(1,1),(1,2)}" does not exist

and

```
INSERT INTO test_composite_array (dx) VALUES('{"(1,1)","(1,2)"}');
```

which appears to work though it leaves me feeling confused since a subsequent

SELECT dx FROM test_composite_array

returns what appears to be a string result `{"(1,1),(1,2)}` although a further query such as

```
SELECT id FROM test_composite_array WHERE (dx[1]).tslot = 1;
```

works.  I also tried the following

```
SELECT (dx[1]).day FROM test_composite_array;
UPDATE test_composite_array SET dx[1].day = 99 WHERE (dx[1]).tslot = 1;
SELECT (dx[1]).day FROM test_composite_array;
```

which works while

```
 UPDATE test_composite_array SET (dx[1]).day = 99 WHERE (dx[1]).tslot = 1;
```

fails.  I find that I am figuring out how to manipulate arrays of records/composite types in Postgres by trial and error and - altough Postgres documentation is generally excellent - there appears to be no clear discussion of this topic in the documentation. I'd be much obliged to anyone who can point me to an authoritative discussion of how to manipulate arrays of composite types in Postgres.

That apart are there any unexpected gotchas when working with such arrays?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need square brackets with `ARRAY`:

```
ARRAY[ROW(1,1)::dow_id,ROW(1,2)::dow_id]
```

A warning: composite types are a great feature, but you will make your life harder if you overuse them. As soon as you want to use elements of a composite type in `WHERE` or `JOIN` conditions, you are doing something wrong, and you are going to suffer. There are good reasons for normalizing relational data.

Comment: Thank you.  You imply that using composite types with `WHERE` conditions is not a good idea.  Could you elaborate a bit on that?  What sort of complications/limitations does it provoke?

Comment: Thanks for the correction! Just try to come up with a `SELECT` that filters the results based on one attribute of any array element in a `dow_id[]`. You'll find that such a query is difficult to write, and you could not speed it up with an index.