# Postgres - partial matches for composite types in an array

Tags: sql, arrays, postgresql, record, composite

This question follows on from a [previous one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59812263/postgres-crud-operations-with-arrays-of-composite-types/59818677#59818677) I had posed here.  Once again, consider the following example

```
CREATE TYPE dow_id AS
(
 tslot smallint,
 day smallint
);

CREATE SEQUENCE test_id_seq INCREMENT 1 MINVALUE 1 MAXVALUE 2147483647 START 1 CACHE 1;

CREATE TABLE test_composite_array 
(
 id integer DEFAULT nextval('test_id_seq') NOT NULL,
 dx  dow_id[]
);
```

where I have done the following

- defined a composite type
- created a table that uses the previously defined composite type in an array column

I can now go and populate that table.  For example

```
INSERT INTO test_composite_array (dx) VALUES(ARRAY[CAST(ROW(1,1) AS dow_id),CAST(ROW(1,2) AS dow_id)]);
INSERT INTO test_composite_array (dx) VALUES(ARRAY[CAST(ROW(2,1) AS dow_id),CAST(ROW(2,2) AS dow_id)]); 
INSERT INTO test_composite_array (dx) VALUES(ARRAY[CAST(ROW(3,1) AS dow_id),CAST(ROW(3,2) AS dow_id)]);
```

Following which I can issue the following queries

SELECT * FROM test_composite_array;

which yields

> **id**         **dw**
>
> 9 {"(1,1)","(1,2)"}
>
> 10 {"(2,1)","(2,2)"}
>
> 11 {"(3,1)","(3,2)"}
>
> 12 {"(3,1)","(3,-2)"}

OR

```
 select id from test_composite_array where ROW(CAST(3 AS SMALLINT),CAST(-2 AS SMALLINT)) = ANY(dx);
```

which yields

> id
>
> 12

But suppose I want to get **all rows** where the `day` value is 2 - i.e. I don't really care what the `tslot` value is.  In my example the result returned should be the rows with `id's` **10**, **11** and **12**.  It is not clear to me how/whether I can do this.

Comment: The difficulty to write such a condition in SQL is a wonderful example for my warning in the answer to [your other question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59812263/postgres-crud-operations-with-arrays-of-composite-types). Try a different data model without arrays and composite keys. You will be richly rewarded by simpler and more performant SQL.

Comment: Thanks - exactly what I had suspected.  I am going to try to cast things differently to avoid a dependence of composite types.